# Layer Lost Focus

Tags: javascript, focus

I'm coding a combo box of sorts right now.  While I've gotten as far as to show a div layer at a particular location after clicking an image, I'm not sure how to hide the layer if I click on ANY OTHER part of the webpage.  Like a dropdown list works when it loses focus.

I'm trying to duplicate the functionality seen here:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the click event on the whole document, and within it hide all the menus.  Then on your combo box, stop propogation on the click event...

```
 $(document).click(function() {
   //Hide all visible menus
 });

 $(".comboBox").click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

More info on [stopPropagation](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event%23event.stopPropagation.28.29&usg=AFQjCNHhDMRFNAmOynoylo97Vwi8ZwVjjg&ei=qeSwSsXMJcOktgfj3oHWBw&sa=X&oi=section_link&resnum=1&ct=legacy).

Comment: For anyone that runs across this question in the future, Josh is using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an event listener to the click event of the `document` object. It won't work just as well if you assign it to the `body`. The document element actually expands to the whole view port, which is not necessarily true for the `body` element.